# Drag and drop / save / changs

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to know how Can I save the page style after drag and drop , sort , collapse and store them to another page of the same components ? but I need so save them by client side don't need to use server side or database.

Comment: You need to show the code you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Save the positions( and other states) in the localStorage and on load read it from there and apply the positions to your divs.

Here you find out how to save and read something from Localstorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage

Then you have to read your styles, what you want to save for example with jquery and save it there.

Comment: Added the url to the documentation. More is hard without any code from your side